# Not getting required output upon click

Tags: javascript, onclick

> Reference Error: function is not defined

This is the part where I'm  getting the error. Actually  I'm  making a Instagram like interface. when I click `home/search/profile` etc button I should get the respective interface visible but I'm  getting this error.

In HTML I mention the `onclick` events and the inner interfaces like home, profile etc are made `display: none;`.

```js
function show(n)
{
    const displayOptions = [ "none", "block" ];
    document.getElementsByClassName( "home" )[0].style.display = displayOptions[ Number( n === 1) ];
    document.getElementsByClassName( "searchCont" )[0].style.display = displayOptions[ Number( n === 2) ];
    document.getElementsByClassName( "uploadCont" )[0].style.display = displayOptions[ Number( n === 3) ];
    document.getElementsByClassName( "notificationCont" )[0].style.display = displayOptions[ Number( n === 4) ];
    document.getElementsByClassName( "profileCont" )[0].style.display = displayOptions[ Number( n === 5) ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a boolean to number, here: `Number( n === 1)`.

I think you meant: `document.getElementsByClassName( "home" )[0].style.display = displayOptions[1];`

Comment: No , the code works....but when I try it in the app I made don't work